# Are modern quad-core laptops such as i7-7700 Intel processor , SISD type or SIMD type or MIMD type?

Tags: processor

Logically, if there are four cores in a CPU, then executing four different instructions each with its own data would be ideal. In that case CPU should ideally be MIMD type. But I read that until 2010, most computers were SISD type even with multiple cores on it. Then somewhere I read modern computers are of SIMD type, but its not clear if they are referring to CPU or GPU in that case. Please clarify it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Intel Core i7 has several cores and is clearly MIMD. Each one of these cores has AVX instructions, so each core can be seen as SIMD since AVX is an extension of the latter where a single operation can handle eight 32-bit floating-point operations or four 64-bit floating-point operations.